# Main thread loop unexpectedly exited! fire base error

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

When I call

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
```

in my application, I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Main thread loop unexpectedly exited
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: can you post more code ?

Comment: I called it from another activity that is not login activity? Sorry i have no the permission to upload codes!

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Also show some context for the line of code that causes the error.